# Remove thousand separator of year in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull year data from a table, but the results show thousand separator e.g. 2021 become 2,021. What should I do to remove the comma? Here's a simple version of my query:

```
select table.year from table
```

-Update-

The datatype is smallint, and the syntax below worked. Thank you!

```
SELECT CAST(year AS varchar(4)) AS year FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Are you very sure the *database* returns that value with a comma (and thus returns a *string*) or does the way you view that integer value "helpfully" add that comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing could be due to that, for whatever reason, the `year` column of your table happens to be decimal.  Or, it could be that your SQL tool/client likes to format all numbers with thousands separators.  In either case, the following workaround might work:

```sql
SELECT CAST(year AS varchar(4)) AS year
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Almost certainly the tool/client, I'd expect? In which case possibly there is no problem at all; it'll "just work" when it's made part of a larger piece of code, and the `varchar` workaround will break things...

Comment: @JiříBaum The OP asked about a certain query, to which I have given a text trick workaround.  If there be some _other_ query here, let the OP comment.

Comment: Yeah, just trying to be more helpful for the OP; depending on the context, it may be that there is in fact no problem, only a minor presentation issue, and attempting to work around it will make things worse rather than better

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, check the datatype of your column.

If you're storing year only, it might be a simple int

OR

just replace the comma

```
SELECT REPLACE(table.year,',','') from table
```

OR type convert it

```
SELECT year(CAST( table.year as datetime )) from yourtable
```